# Identifying Toilet Pipe

Tags: bathroom

First time positing to this channel. However, I wondered if someone could help me identify the white pipe above the waste running to this toilet?

My understanding was that toilets traditionally have a waste pipe, and a water supply (running to the cistern). However, this toilet has a pipe beyond the waste running into the toilet.

Would appreciate some feedback on its name/function, and if re-installing a toilet, it would be necessary in a new unit?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Guessing without knowing more, where it comes from and where it goes, would guess an extra pipe for venting.  How far away is the stack/pipe used for vent, the one that should go though the roof?

Comment: Hi @crip659. Managed to get a panel off for a better photo. I can't see any type of ventilation running from it, must admit.

Comment: To me, that looks like the supply line from the cistern to the bowl itself. Can you [edit] a broader view picture in to give us more of an overview of the whole installation?

Comment: Is the toilet tank on the toilet bowl or is it the black looking tank seen in new picture?  If so then it is the flush pipe/tube that flushes the toilet.  Should have a smaller pipe going to it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their feedback. Novice question, it's contributed much more to my understanding. I now get why there's a separate pipe based on the installation-type. It's a separate supply line, given that the cistern is separate from the bowl. Thanks to Freeman, crip659, and JACK. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most toilets have the cistern attached to the bowl so there's no pipe needed. This particular type has the cistern separated from the bowl so that pipe feeds water into the top of the bowl from the cistern to start the flush. You'll find a supply line that feeds the cistern around there.

Comment: Thanks Jack - I appreciate your time.

Comment: @EB3112, be sure and upvote helpful questions.  You can upvote and accept the same answer to give the user a few more points.

Comment: @EB3112 the up vote and check mark (which you've clicked) also help other to know that this question has a useful answer that resolved the problem for you. It's a flag to others to know that they might find their answer here, too.